# where is the source code for the standard library in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

when looking at the standard library of OCaml I want to see the source code for the functions described, where can i find the code for these functions?

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html this link shows the standard library for list, where can I find the code used for each of these?

Comment: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/index.html ? I just clicked "Up" on your link :\

Answer (score 11):

just type as follows in your shell:

```
$ cd `ocamlc -where`
```

And you can see *.mli files, which has documentations.

Answer (score 8):

The source code is available to browse from the OCaml Subversion repository:

http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/anonsvn.en.html

For example, the stdlib code for the latest in-development OCaml version is here:

http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/ocaml/trunk/stdlib/

There is a read-only mirror on github:

https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml

The standard library code is also available from an OCaml source tarball if you would prefer to download everything:

http://caml.inria.fr/download.en.html

Answer (score 3):

As ymotongpoo pointed out, the interface files of the standard library are part of a normal OCaml isntallation. To see the actual source code, you have to download the source of the OCaml compiler from [caml.inria.fr](http://caml.inria.fr). The implementation of the standard library can be found in directory "stdlib/".

Answer (score 0):

Install ocamlbrowser, then look for the module your are interested
into, then click the implementation button.